# GRUB skipped in dual boot

Tags: grub2, dual-boot, windows-7

I've downloaded the latest Ubuntu, 12.04. I have Windows 7 Professional installed on my laptop, 1 physical HD divided to 3 partitions (C:, D: and System Reserved). I shrank D: drive and had 60 GB of unallocated space. Rebooted from Ubuntu install cd and installed it with the option of Install Alongside Windows 7.

After installation is over, Windows loads automatically; not GRUB, Ubuntu doesn't show up in the Boot tab in msconfig.

Done this several times, same result always. Am I doing something wrong? A while back when I installed 11.10, I had different issues (GRUB won't load, only GRUB4DOS) but eventually I managed to install it. Now, after formatting and reinstalling Windows 7 (Original, not that it matters), I'm stuck.

Any suggestions? Thanks!

Comment: Hey There,  Just out of curiosity which drive are you booting from?  C: or D:  ??   Have you tried switching the boot disk in the bios. It's quite possible that grub was installed on the alternate disk.

Comment: It's the same physical HD.. or maybe I didn't understand what u ment

Comment: You might need a boot flag on your Ubuntu partition, that was an issue I needed to go through.

Answer (score 1):

First, might be a 12.04 installer bug...which is off topic.

Second, you should be able to install grub from live like [this](https://askubuntu.com/questions/88384/how-can-i-repair-grub-how-to-get-ubuntu-back-after-installing-windows).

Answer (score 1):

An easier way then the previous answer would be using [Boot-Repair](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Boot-Repair) to install grub.

Answer (score -2):

Open the terminal and type

```
gksu gedit /etc/default/grub
```

And put `#` before this `GRUB_HIDDEN_TIMEOUT=0`

It will look like this `#GRUB_HIDDEN_TIMEOUT=0`.

Save it and type:

```
sudo reboot
```

Hopes this helps. If not, I have another way. I will tell you if this fails. But this solution solved my problem today.

Comment: This answer only can be use if user can boot to Ubuntu.

Comment: yup I actually misinterpreted that title .